# {logs: Array(8) programErrorStack: em stack:failed to send transaction:failed to send transaction:Transaction Instruction 2:Program failed to complete

Tags: error, sendtransactionerror

```
use anchor_lang::{
    prelude::*,
    solana_program::{clock::Clock, hash::hash, program::invoke, system_instruction::transfer},
};

mod constants;
mod error;

use crate::{constants::*, error::*};

// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("3pnK5jN5wqPRZibeepWNixtJhfSPPa8YShrr1CwFJwca");

#[program]
mod lottery {
    use super::*;

    pub fn init_master(_ctx: Context<InitMaster>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn create_lottery(ctx: Context<CreateLottery>, ticket_price: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let lottery = &mut ctx.accounts.lottery;
        let master = &mut ctx.accounts.master;

        master.last_id += 1;

        lottery.id = master.last_id;
        lottery.authority = ctx.accounts.authority.key();
        lottery.ticket_price = ticket_price;
        msg!("Created lottery: {}", lottery.id);
        msg!("Authority: {}", lottery.authority);
        msg!("Ticket price: {}", lottery.ticket_price);

        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn buy_ticket(ctx: Context<BuyTicket>, lottery_id: u32) -> Result<()> {
        let lottery = &mut ctx.accounts.lottery;
        let ticket = &mut ctx.accounts.ticket;
        let buyer = &ctx.accounts.buyer;

        if lottery.winner_id.is_some() {
            return err!(LotteryError::WinnerAlreadyExists);
        }

        invoke(
            &transfer(&buyer.key(), &lottery.key(), lottery.ticket_price),
            &[
                buyer.to_account_info(),
                lottery.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
        )?;
        lottery.last_ticket_id += 1;
        ticket.id = lottery.last_ticket_id;
        ticket.lottery_id = lottery_id;
        ticket.authority = buyer.key();

        msg!("Ticket id: {}", ticket.id);
        msg!("Ticket authority: {}", ticket.authority);

        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn pick_winner(ctx: Context<PickWinner>, _lottery_id: u32) -> Result<()> {
        let lottery = &mut ctx.accounts.lottery;

        if lottery.winner_id.is_some() {
            return err!(LotteryError::WinnerAlreadyExists);
        }
        if lottery.last_ticket_id == 0 {
            return err!(LotteryError::NoTickets);
        }

        let clock = Clock::get()?;
        let pseudo_random_number = ((u64::from_le_bytes(
            <[u8; 8]>::try_from(&hash(&clock.unix_timestamp.to_be_bytes()).to_bytes()[..8])
                .unwrap(),
        ) * clock.slot)
            % u32::MAX as u64) as u32;

        let winner_id = (pseudo_random_number % lottery.last_ticket_id) + 1;
        lottery.winner_id = Some(winner_id);

        msg!("Winner id: {}", winner_id);

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn claim_prize(ctx: Context<ClaimPrize>, _lottery_id: u32, _ticket_id: u32) -> Result<()> {
        let lottery = &mut ctx.accounts.lottery;
        let ticket = &ctx.accounts.ticket;
        let winner = &ctx.accounts.authority;

        if lottery.claimed {
            return err!(LotteryError::AlreadyClosed);
        }

        match lottery.winner_id {
            Some(winner_id) => {
                if winner_id != ticket.id {
                    return err!(LotteryError::InvalidWinner);
                }
            }
            None => return err!(LotteryError::WinnerNotChosen),
        }

        let total_prize = lottery
            .ticket_price
            .checked_mul(lottery.last_ticket_id.into())
            .unwrap();

        let fee_amount = total_prize.checked_mul(25).unwrap() / 100;
        // Calculate the remaining prize amount after deducting the fee
        let remaining_prize = total_prize.checked_sub(fee_amount).unwrap(); // Assume total_fee is calculated elsewhere

        // Transfer the remaining prize amount to the winner's account
        **lottery.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= remaining_prize;
        **winner.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += remaining_prize;
        let fee_account_lamports = **ctx.accounts.fee_account.to_account_info().lamports.borrow();
        if fee_account_lamports < fee_amount {
            return err!(LotteryError::InsufficientFeeFunds);
        }

        // Transfer the fee amount to the fee account
        **lottery.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= fee_amount;
        **ctx
            .accounts
            .fee_account
            .to_account_info()
            .try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += fee_amount;

        lottery.claimed = true;

        msg!(
            "{} claimed {} lamports from lottery id {} with ticket id {}",
            winner.key(),
            remaining_prize,
            lottery.id,
            ticket.id,
        );

        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitMaster<'info> {
    // We must specify the space in order to initialize an account.
    // First 8 bytes are default account discriminator,
    // next 8 bytes come from NewAccount.data being type u64.
    // (u64 = 64 bits unsigned integer = 8 bytes)
    #[account(init,
         payer = payer, 
         space = 4 + 8, 
         seeds=[MASTER_SEED.as_bytes()],
         bump,
     )]
    pub master: Account<'info, Master>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Master {
    pub last_id: u32,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateLottery<'info> {
    #[account(
    init,
        payer = authority, 
        space =4 + 32 + 8 + 4 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 8 + 36, 
        seeds = [LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &(master.last_id + 1).to_le_bytes()],
         bump,
     )]
    pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,

    #[account(
         mut,
         seeds = [MASTER_SEED.as_bytes()],
         bump,
     )]
    pub master: Account<'info, Master>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Lottery {
    pub id: u32,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub ticket_price: u64,
    pub last_ticket_id: u32,
    pub winner_id: Option<u32>,
    pub claimed: bool,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(lottery_id:u32)]
pub struct BuyTicket<'info> {
    #[account(
            mut,
            seeds = [LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &lottery_id.to_le_bytes()],
            bump,
        )]
    pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,

    #[account(
            init,
            payer= buyer,
            space= 4 + 4 + 32 + 8,
            seeds= [
                TICKET_SEED.as_bytes(),
                lottery.key().as_ref(),
                &(lottery.last_ticket_id + 1).to_le_bytes(), 
            ],
            bump
        )]
    pub ticket: Account<'info, Ticket>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Ticket {
    pub id: u32,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub lottery_id: u32,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(lottery_id: u32)]

pub struct PickWinner<'info> {
    #[account(
         mut,
         seeds=[LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &lottery_id.to_le_bytes()],
         bump,
         has_one = authority,
    )]
    pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(lottery_id: u32, ticket_id: u32)]
pub struct ClaimPrize<'info> {
    #[account(
         mut,
         seeds = [LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &lottery_id.to_le_bytes()],
         bump,
    )]
    pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,
    #[account(
         seeds = [
             TICKET_SEED.as_bytes(),
             lottery.to_account_info().key.as_ref(),
             &ticket_id.to_le_bytes()
         ],
         bump,
         has_one = authority,    
    )]
    pub ticket: Account<'info, Ticket>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    
    #[account(init, payer = authority, space = 36, seeds = [FEE_ACCOUNT_SEED.as_bytes()], bump,)]
    pub fee_account: Account<'info, FeeAccount>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct FeeAccount {
    pub fee_account: Pubkey,
    pub lottery_id: u32,
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Solana Stack Exchange! When asking questions, you're more likely to get an answer when the question is clear (the reader knows what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what didn't work as you expected). It's also critical that the code in the question is readable. Right now this post needs improvement in both of those areas.

Comment: Hello! If you don't mind, can you include both the handler function of the instruction that caused this error and a full copy of the error logs? This error is usually caused by an error in your instruction and so both are required for additional context to help give an helpful answer.